# How can I use a variable name to refer to an import in React?

Tags: reactjs, import, font-awesome

I have a series of objects that look like this:

```
{
  color: '#7018A7',
  icon: 'User',
  label: 'todd',
  text: "Lorem ipsum..."
},
```

I need to use my icon property inside a Font Awesome Component `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon}`. However, I'm importing the icons I need `import {faUser} from '<font awesome library>'`. Of course, if I interpolate the icon's name (`` icon={`fa${icon}`} ``), I get an error because it is not equal to the actual imported icon.

Is there any way to refer to the imported icon by using the variable/property name?

Answer (score 0):

The problem: FontAwesomeIcon does not accept a string as an argument.

The solution: have the icon property's value set to the imported icon

`icon: faUser`